# An $\epsilon$ -neighborhood of a convex set is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, metric-spaces

Denote the $\epsilon$ -neighborhood of $A$ by $B(A,\epsilon)$, $$B(A,\epsilon):=\{y \in \mathbb R^n: d(y,A)\le \epsilon \}$$

**Prove that if A is convex set, then $B(A,\epsilon)$ is also a convex set.**

Define $d(x,\mathbb X)=\inf\{d(x,y) ,y \in \mathbb X\}$, and $d(x,y)= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2}$ (Eucledian distance).

Please help me. Thanks.

**Edit**: Let x'' be written in the convex combination of x and x'. We want to prove that $d(x'',A) \le \epsilon$

Comment: Do you have any idea? Some theorem you know that might be helpful?

Answer (score 3):

This follows because $\overline A$ and the standard $\epsilon$-ball are convex: A point $x\in B(A,\epsilon)$ can be written as $a+u$ with $a\in\overline A$ and $|u|\le\epsilon$. If $x'=a'+u'$ is another such point, then convex combinations are $$\underbrace{ta+(1-t)a'}_{\in \overline A}+\underbrace{tu+(1-t)u'}_{|\cdot|\le \epsilon} $$

Comment: Is it possible to prove by letting x'' be written in the convex combination of, say x and x'? Let $x''= tx+(1-t)x$, then prove that $d(x'',A) \le \epsilon$